# new SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined in mobile device browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, kiosk, speech-synthesis

Hello can you help me regarding speech synthesis in normal use if browser like chrome it's working, but when i use kiosk mode app in android and running google chrome as browser there's an error SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined. any encounter regarding this matter?

Please help.
Thank you.

```
const speak = () => {
    const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(data.description);
    speech.voice = voices?.find((x: any) => x.name === 'Google US English');
    speech.rate = rate;

    //window.speechSynthesis
    ws.speak(speech);

  };
```

Comment: Looks like it is not supported. Develop a browser based web app then.